# Convert Device context logical coordinates to screen coordinates

Tags: windows, winapi, gdi

How to convert a device context logical coordinates to screen coordinates. LPToDP can be used to convert logical coordinates to device coordinates, but those device coordinates are not client coordinates. So ClientToScreen cannot be used to convert those coordinates to screen coordinates. So how can we convert ?

Comment: DPToLP just convert logical coordinates to device coordinates, but how to convert these device coordinates to screen coordinates.

Comment: i got the solution.... there is one more function GetDCOrgEx. The GetDCOrgEx function retrieves the final translation origin for a specified device context (DC). The final translation origin specifies an offset that the system uses to translate device coordinates into client coordinates (for coordinates in an application's window).